# Flutter - is there a way to execute a method periodically even when app is not open

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a personal expenses app in which I have a Week model which holds user expanses over week and at the end of the week uploads it in cloud. My problem is that how can I implement a situation in which Week model is created at first day of week(eg.saturday) periodically even if the app is not running??? Is that even possible??
I searched a little and saw

`timer.periodic(duration,callback);`

but I don't think that would work in background

Comment: You must configure a receiver. Google for it.

Comment: In my opinion this shouldn't be done in the application itself, but in the backend system.

Comment: @Yann39 I think you're right but I don't know how to if you could help with some keywords I could search for would be great

Comment: As per the proposed answers there are solutions and hacks to run background jobs, but this is usually not a good practice. Running tasks in background is often something discouraged on mobile systems. Most of mobile applications are dealing with services/API to expose data, so most of the time you can have your backend system (application server, database) do that kind of job. Of course it all depends on your application architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you:

1. **Firstly**

You have to use `Timer` from `dart:async` to run periodically method, and put the duration for 7 days.

```dart
  Timer.periodic(
    Duration(days: 7),
    (timer){
      // Create new week model in database.
    }
  );
```

2. **Secondly**

Use `workmanager` to run the previous code in the background, it will executed weekly.

Comment: Thanks but where should I write timer?? In initState?? wouldn't that just create a timer every time The app opens?

Comment: You can do this in main function, or any place supported by `workmanager`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [background_fetch](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch) plugin. But this plugin's lack of it is that works stable on just Android. You need to read the official document.